# How to set multiple api Key with Swashbuckle in the request's header

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, api-key, swashbuckle

I've a web api2 project, where I've implemented swashbuckle for test and documentation of my web services.
I've tried to set an apiKey for the authentication in the SwaggerDocsConfig and it works, but if I want to add another apiKey (**apiKey** and **appId**) I can't make it works.

I read in the [swagger doc](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/api-keys/) that is possible, but I don't get how to configuring the swagger docs in this way, with swashbuckle.

*How Swagger docs should be*

```
securityDefinitions:
  apiKey:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: X-API-KEY
  appId:
    type: apiKey
    in: header
    name: X-APP-ID
security:
  - apiKey: []
    appId: []
```

I've tried to simply add another ApiKey when I enable swagger in my project (see code above), but it didn't work.

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger(swagger =>
            {
                swagger.RootUrl(req => req.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).TrimEnd('/') + req.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot.TrimStart('/'));
                swagger.PrettyPrint();
                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Project.WebApi");             
                swagger.ApiKey("apiKey") //First ApiKey
                    .Description("API Key Authentication")
                    .Name("Authorization")
                    .In("header");
                swagger.ApiKey("apiId") //Second ApiKey
                    .Description("API Key Authentication")
                    .Name("Authorization") //Same Schema
                    .In("header");                              
                swagger.IncludeXmlComments(string.Format(@"{0}\bin\Project.WebApi.XML", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory));
                swagger.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
            })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(swagger =>
            {
                swagger.DocumentTitle("Project API");               
                swagger.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.List);
                swagger.EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector();
                swagger.EnableApiKeySupport("Authorization", "header");
            });
```

Is it possible to do it with Swashbuckle, or I have to inject an js script and do it from client-side?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Swashbuckle are you using?

Comment: The last version currently available: 5.6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested this with [Swagger-Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net) and it seems to work fine...
Here is a fully functional example:

http://nhc-noaa.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=&docExpansion=list

Once you enter the apiKey and appId the curl looks like this:

```
curl -X GET "http://nhc-noaa.azurewebsites.net/api/Videos?count=1&frameRate=1&isCompressed=false" 
     -H "accept: application/json" -H "apiKey: 111" -H "appId: 222"
```

Full disclosure I'm the owner of Swagger-Net, the implementation is very similar to swashbuckle, I just try to simplify a lot of the settings, EnableApiKeySupport is one of those things that I completely removed, to do what you ask all you need is:

```
c.ApiKey("apiKey", "header", "API Key Authentication", typeof(KeyAuthorizeAttribute));
c.ApiKey("appId", "header", "APP ID Authentication", typeof(KeyAuthorizeAttribute));
```

Full code is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/nhc-noaa/blob/master/nhc-noaa/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs

Comment: Now I can't test it, tomorrow I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Just a heads up, this solution adds the API keys as _independent_ security requirements - `"security": [ { "apiKey":[] }, { "appId":[] } ]`. This means the client can use either `apiKey` or `appId`. But the OP asked for `"security": [ { "apiKey":[], "appId":[] } ]` - two API keys _in the same security requirement_. (The difference is explained [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/#multiple).)

Comment: Good Point @Helen !

Answer (score 4):

The @HelderSepu's response works, but I found another solution that maybe can help someone that for some reasone can't move from Swashbuckle to Swagger-Net.

It is possible to create a custom OperationFilter object, where you can set additional parameters in each call in this way:

```
public class AuthTokenHeaderParameter : IOperationFilter
{       
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.parameters == null)
            operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();

        var authorizeAttributes = apiDescription
            .ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AuthorizeAttribute>();

        if (authorizeAttributes.ToList().Any(attr => attr.GetType() == typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute)) == false)
        {
            operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter()
            {
                name = "ApiKey",
                @in = "header",
                type = "string",
                description = "Authorization Token. Please remember the Bearer part",
                @default = "Bearer ",
                required = true
            });
            operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter()
            {
                name = "AppId",
                @in = "header",
                type = "string",
                description = "AppId",
                required = true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then you have to implement it when you configure Swagger in this way:

```
c.OperationFilter<AuthTokenHeaderParameter>();
```

I hope this may help someone.